# How to control number of records stored in a part file by pig job or a maprecude job?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, apache-pig

Is there a way to control number of records to be stored in a part file?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Not easily (if at all). The number of part files in the output is determined by the parallelism of the script, and the data is split up non-deterministically into those part files. The only way I can think of is something like:

```
A = FOREACH output GENERATE 1 AS num ;
B = FOREACH (GROUP A ALL) GENERATE COUNT(A) AS totaloutputlines ; 
-- Then store both output and B
```

Then, from within a python wrapper, use `totaloutputlines` to set the parallelism of the script the python wrapper is running, so that `PAR = number of lines in B / number of lines you want per file`.  That will *hopefully*, *approximately* control the number of records per part file.

Maybe you can get something close to what you want with [`MultiStorage`](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.10.0/api/org/apache/pig/piggybank/storage/MultiStorage.html) by splitting the output into one file per value of the field you use.